# Electron app Express server is slow for GET request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, electron

We created a web server using Express for an Electron app but the performance for GET request is very slow! Any specific reason for that?

you can download the application and source code here http://openspeedtest.com/speed-testing-application-for-your-website.php#Option-3

But post request is performing very well.

Index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const internalIp = require('internal-ip');
const tcpPortUsed = require('tcp-port-used');




const ExpressApp = express();
global.ExpressApp = ExpressApp;

ExpressApp.use(cors());

ExpressApp.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
global.ExpressApp = ExpressApp;
ExpressApp.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  req.body = null;
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


//npm install
//npx create-electron-app openspeedtest-server
//npm start
//npm run make
// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
//app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('ready', function () {
  var IPadd = internalIp.v4.sync();
  var Port = 3000;

  //console.log(internalIp.v6.sync())




  //tcpPortUsed.check(Port, IPadd)
  getPort = function (Port) {
    tcpPortUsed.check(Port, IPadd)
      .then(function (inUse) {
        console.log('Port ' + Port + " in use =  " + inUse);
        if (inUse) {
          Port = Port + 1;
          console.log('Trying new port = ' + Port)
          getPort(Port)
          //console.error('Error on check:', err.message);
        } else {
          console.log(Port + " is Free!")
          var ExpressAppServer = ExpressApp.listen(Port, function () {
            global.ExpressAppServer = ExpressAppServer;
            //var port = ExpressAppServer.address().port;
            console.log('OpenSpeedTest-Server is running..', IPadd, ':', Port);
            createWindow();
          });




        }
      }, function (err) {

      });

  }

  getPort(Port)
  // var ExpressAppServer = ExpressApp.listen(80, function () {
  //global.ExpressAppServer = ExpressAppServer;
  // var port = ExpressAppServer.address().port;

  //console.log('App now running on ', IPadd, ':', port);
  //createWindow();
  //});
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    //BrowserWindow({ icon: 'src/icon.png' });
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OpenSpeedTest-Server Ver:1.0</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#56c4fb), to(#0baeff)) fixed;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
      /* Green */
      border: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 22px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .port {
      border: 9px #008CBA;
      border-radius: 15px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <h1>OpenSpeedtest-Server Ver:1.0</h1></br></br>
  <h1>Network Speed Test Server Status : Running...</h1></br></br>
  <h1>
    <div id=ipadder></div>
  </h1></br></br>

  <h1>Change Port If Needed.</h1></br></br>
  <input class="port" type="number" id="ChangePort"></input>
  <button class="button" type="submit" id="restart">Update & Restart Server</button>

  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      let expressServer = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('ExpressAppServer');
      const express = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('ExpressApp');
      const internalIp = require('internal-ip');

      //const cors = require('cors').remote.getGlobal('cors');
      var port = expressServer.address().port;

      console.log(internalIp.v4.sync() + " " + port)
      var ipadder = document.getElementById('ipadder');
      ipadder.innerHTML = ("Please visit this url : " + 'http://' + internalIp.v4.sync() + ":" + port)

      document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var newPort = document.getElementById("ChangePort").value;
        expressServer.close();
        expressServer = express.listen(newPort, function () {
          var port = expressServer.address().port;
          ipadder.innerHTML = ("Please visit this url : " + 'http://' + internalIp.v4.sync() + ":" + port)
          //console.log('App now running on port', port);
        });


      });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Openspeedtest-server",
  "productName": "Openspeedtest-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Network Speed Test Server - by OpenSpeedTest",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "OpenSpeedTest",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "src/icon.icns"
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "openspeedtest_server",
            "icon": "src/icon.ico",
            "setupIcon": "src/icon.ico"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {
            "icon": "src/1024x1024.png"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "internal-ip": "^6.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "tcp-port-used": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "electron": "^9.1.0"
  }
}
```